# Webpack can't resolve relative path import express static

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I'm working on an outlook addin I have an express server running. I am setting webpack because I need to transpile js to es5 to make it work in Outlook Desktop. Here is the simplified project structure.

```
/public
  /javascripts
    ssoAuth.js
/addin
  /commmands
    commands.js
    commands.html
/server
  /bin
  /helpers
  app.js
```

The public folder is set as a static folder in my express server

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public'),
```

My problem is in commands.js I import ssoAuth.js with es6 module import with relative path :

```
import getGraphAccessToken from "/javascripts/ssoAuthES6.js";
```

It works fine when I run node ./server/app.js and load my outlook addin, but when I want to use Webpack to bundle, the import is not working, I get :

```
ERROR in ./addin/commands/commands.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/javascripts/ssoAuth.js'
```

I can't figure out how to configure webpack to allow the imports from the public folder.

Here are my webpack config files :

webpack.config.js :

```
const config = {
devtool: "source-map",
entry: {
  polyfill: "@babel/polyfill",
  commands: "./addin/commands/commands.js"
},
resolve: {
  extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"]
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader", 
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: "html-loader"
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
      use: "file-loader"
    }
  ]
},
plugins: [
  new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: "commands.html",
    template: "./addin/commands/commands.html",
    chunks: ["polyfill", "commands"]
  })
]};
```

webpack.server.config.js :

```
return ({
entry: {
  server: './server/bin/www',
},
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: '[name].js'
},
target: 'node',
node: {
  __dirname: false,
  __filename: false,
},
externals: [nodeExternals()], 
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      // Transpiles ES6-8 into ES5
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    }
  ]
},
plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
      to: "./public",
      from: "./public"
    }
  ])
]})
```

Can you help figure this out ? Is there a better folder structure that I should use to make it work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an absolute path

```js
import getGraphAccessToken from "/javascripts/ssoAuthES6.js";
//                               ^ this will look in your topmost directory on your OS
```

The relative path, from `commands.js`, would be:

```js
import getGraphAccessToken from "../../javascripts/ssoAuthES6.js";
```

---

Alternatively, you can set Webpack to look for modules from your root directory by adding the following to your webpack configuration:

```json
{
// ...
    resolve: {
      modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"],
    },
// ...
}
```

Then you can import from your project's root directory from anywhere, like so:

```
import getGraphAccessToken from "javascripts/ssoAuthES6.js";
```

---

Some other points:

- Since you're setting the `extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"]`, you don't need to provide file extensions for those imports
- You specify `.ts` and `.tsx` in your webpack config, but you are using `.js` files. Consider removing the Typescript extensions
- If you *are* using Typescript, you will need to update import paths in your `tsconfig.json`
- You can consider import path aliases in both Webpack and Typescript to be more explicit that your imports are coming from your project root. [Instructions here](https://medium.com/@davidmieloch/tilde-paths-with-eslint-typescript-and-webpack-971f694c9b15)